# popup using tapgesture on a TableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, popup, cgpoint

I have a TableView with custom cells containing multiple labels. I added a tapgesture on one of these labels so a popup will appear. The problem is, the popup doesn't appear where it should be (centered and on top of the label).

What's wrong with the line:

```
[self.popupMenu showInView:self.view atPoint:CGPointMake(label.center.x, label.frame.origin.y)];
```

tableview.m:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // add a tap gesture recognizer
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTap:)];
    [cell.customAmountLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    NSString *ItemName = [NSString stringWithCString:CurrentOrder[indexPath.row].c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *ItemAmount = [NSString stringWithCString:CurrentOrder[indexPath.row].c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    cell.customNameLabel.text = ItemName;
    cell.customAmountLabel.text = ItemAmount;

    return cell;
}
```

method for tap gesture:

```
- (void)labelTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    // get location of the swipe
    CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableCurrentOrder];

    // get the corresponding index path within the table view
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableCurrentOrder indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

    // check if index path is valid
    if(indexPath)
    {
        // get the cell out of the table view
        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [self.tableCurrentOrder cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // update the cell or model
        std::cout << CurrentOrder[indexPath.row] << std::endl;

        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)cell.customAmountLabel;

        [self.popupMenu showInView:self.view atPoint:CGPointMake(label.center.x, label.frame.origin.y)];
    }
}
```

Comment: cell variable may become a nil. you would better make a check routine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to pop up any view once the cell is tapped? If yes, then I recommend you use the `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method in your CustomCell class.

You will be able to know where the tap was using the `event` argument of the method.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches]; 
    for (UITouch *touch in allTouches) 
    { 
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        (...)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jack Thank you for revision. My answer looks better and more natural than before.